# Is there a kanji for しか?

Tags: kanji, particles

Is there kanji for しか as in

> 商品がひとつしかありません。

Comment: I don't think しかし and しか are related etymologically, but on the off chance... 然し is the kanji there

Comment: @ssb I wouldn't think they come from the same root.

Comment: Yeah, more a potentially interesting "fyi" than anything. The more I look the more I think しか just doesn't have kanji... I wonder how it was written in manyougana?

Comment: I've submitted etymology requests for both words in the English Wiktionary. I've made a new manyogana tag too and added it here and to a few previous applicable questions. I find this pretty interesting myself.

Comment: @hippietrail Please excuse my ignorance but where can I see those requests in English Wikitonary?

Comment: @ssb I don't think it's old enough for that to be relevant.  The earliest cite in 日国 is dated 1784か.  Martin in *A Reference Grammar of Japanese* reports on p.80 that Ōtsuki derives *sika* from a contraction of *siki* (as in *kore-siki*) plus the particle *wa*.  He says *siki* is of uncertain etymology; a couple suggestions he gives are that it's a variant of *soko* or a shortening of *suk[os]i*, but he doesn't appear to find these explanations satisfying.

Comment: @paullb: Don't worry, you're not ignorant. Many features of the English Wiktionary are extremely well hidden. I only know some things about it because I've been a contributor since 2002 and was formerly very deeply involved. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Requests_for_etymology_(Japanese)

Comment: I had no idea it was such a new particle! Learning new things every day..

Comment: しかも　and しかし can be written 然も　and 然し. The etymology is different, but I think in spite of that, this might be a good choice of kanji spelling for しか if such a thing needed to be invented. The rationale being is that it comes from existing grammatical connecting words.

Comment: Kaz I think you're spot on, but unfortunately we can't just answer as if we need a kanji to be invented. But I do agree with you, that is the kanji i'd go for too. As it stands though, if we used it in a sentence, Japanese people would look at it and go "What?" (I checked) which is enough for me to say its not in the 'current' Japanese language.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there kanji for しか as in. 商品がひとつしかありません。

No. There is no kanji for this usage of しか.

No evidence of a kanji for this しか can be found in any of the aggregated dictionaries:

[Weblio](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%97%E3%81%8B)

[WWWJDIC](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/%7Ejwb/cgi-bin/wwwjdic.cgi?1C)

[goo](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/srch/je/%E3%81%97%E3%81%8B/m0u/tab/)

Comment: +1 for your courage to tell the truth.  「しか」 in that context is a particle and if one knows even the very basic Japanese, one knows only bad thngs could happen if people started writing particles in kanji.  Paticles can easily be sandwitched in between kanji words, which would make Japanese a language almost impossible to read.

Comment: @TokyoNagoya What do you make of the particle だけ, which can be written 丈? I thought that, even though particles are written with 仮名 in contemporary Japanese, some particles can in principle be written with 漢字. (More examples: 程, 等, 迄, ...)

Comment: What about what is written here (http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%97%E3%81%8B) or the readings for 而 (http://www.kanjijiten.net/jiten/2801.html)?

Comment: So, the first link I'm not sure what you're referring to but I'll assume its 然. In the second one: しかして=而して=Thus/and so/and. 
I'm not sure that's the same meaning but I could be convinced it might be. For example: 'One item **and** nothing' in this sense. I think maybe we can. Native speakers what do you think? @TokyoNagoya?

Comment: Is it the same しか as in 然ながら？(http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/examples/jn2/94415/m0u/)

Comment: I think the better question which is posted above is why are you answering a question that you don't know the answer to? (clearly, しか is written exclusively in 仮名 in modern Japanese, but I assume the question of whether it has a kanji is more historical).

Comment: I think I answered the question fine but then all of a sudden something new came about - is that so unheard of? How do you ever really know the answer to something? How can you prove that you know something as fact?

Comment: You can't prove that a fact is in fact a fact, so to speak, but you can do better than present a simple guess (without references) as an answer.

Comment: @TokyoNagoya the partical ヘ also has a Kanji（方）which I first seen in [this question](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15860/how-are-the-noun-%E6%96%B9%E3%80%90%E3%81%B8%E3%80%91-and-the-particle-%E3%81%B8-related)