# How are the noun 方【へ】 and the particle へ related?

Tags: etymology, particle-へ

I looked up [the etymology of　古【いにしえ】 on gogen-allguide](http://gogen-allguide.com/i/inishie.html), and found the following:

> いにしえは、「去る」を意味する動詞「いぬ（往ぬ）」の連用形「イニ」に、過去を示す助動詞「キ」の連体形「シ」がついた「イニシ」が、方向を表す名詞「ヘ（方）」を修飾した「往にし方（いにしへ）」。

This basically says that we take the verb 往ぬ, conjugate it, add the 助動詞 「き」, conjugate again, and finish by adding the *noun* 方【へ】. This was a bit surprising to me, since I've never seen the noun 方【へ】 myself, and was expecting the particle へ to show up there instead.

This is obviously suggestive of some sort of relationship between the noun 方【へ】 and the particle へ. So - what *is* the etymological relationship between the noun 方【へ】 and the particle へ?

Comment: cf. 行方（ゆくえ） 15chars

Comment: @Ash Yeah, when I [looked it up in デジタル大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/197846/m0u/%E3%83%98/), I saw that; however, the usage of へ/え as a noun seems to be separated from its usage as a 接尾語 in 行方, 海辺, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put simply, the particle へ is derived from the noun 方{へ}.

Bjarke Frellesvig provides a brief explanation in his book *A History of the Japanese Language* (page 132).

> … The noun *pye* "side, direction" was being grammaticalized as an *allative* case particle *pye*, but in the Old Japanese period had not yet acquired that status.

As for pronunciation, sound changes would have likely proceeded something like *pye > *pe > *ɸe > *we > e.

Comment: The common romanisations use <ye> for /e/ for some reason, so it doesn't actually reconstruct to *pje, just *pe (though that's probably from a Proto-Japonic *pja or *pia). Just so you know! ^_^

Comment: Do we know if に and/or まで, or any other particles were in use at that time, or what methods were used to provide the meaning of へ?

Comment: Sjiveru, do you have a source? Frellesvig at least argues that what he writes <pye> really was pronounced with a glide in OJ.

Comment: @hippietrail に predates へ (as does までに, though not as an allative marker). Frellesvig describes the Old Japanese *ni* as "the general oblique case, marking both argument and non-argument oblique nominals. The main uses are indirect object, allative, purposive, agent, instrumental, locative, temporal" (p.126). In Old Japanese *made(ni)* was a restrictive particle that could follow nominalized clauses, meaning "until, so much that" (pp.132–133); it didn't come to be used as an allative particle until Early Middle Japanese.

Answer (score 4):

As ファルキエッレ stated, the particle へ is cognate with the noun, variously spelled 方 or 辺, and probably derives from it.  This has been a very productive noun, appearing as a component of many terms in modern Japanese:

- 芦辺 *ashibe*, "reed-covered bank"
- 海辺 *umibe*, "seaside"
- 夕べ *yūbe*, "last night, yesterday evening"

Some modern JA terms aren't necessarily even recognized as compounds:

- 前 *mae*, "front", compound of 目 + 辺 "eye-wards; visible place"
- 家 *ie*, "home", probably a compound of 寝 + 辺 "sleeping place"

This へ may also be cognate with 瓮 (*he*, "container"), from which we get 鍋 *nabe*, "pot", compound of 肴 + 瓮 "side-dish container".

Regarding the use of へ as a particle meaning something like English "to" or "towards", we already see such usage as long ago as in the [*Man'yōshū*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man%27y%C5%8Dsh%C5%AB) poetry of no later than the mid-700s:

- [Poem 3696](http://etext.lib.virginia.edu/japanese/manyoshu/Man15Yo.html#3696):
  新羅奇敝可 伊敝尓可加反流
  *Shiraki he ka / Ihe ni ka kaheru*
  I'll go back to Silla [the kingdom in the north of the Korean peninsula] or to home...

Perhaps in reflection of the noun's sense of "place, general area", the particle へ in the ancient texts denoted "towards, in the direction of" rather than denoting a specific arrival location, and was more often used to indicate faraway places rather than anywhere close by.  In contrast, に was used to denote a specific arrival location and was used for closer places.  The vaguer connotations of へ ("in the direction of a place") still persist to some extent in modern Japanese and contrast with the more specific connotations of に ("specifically to a place").